# Формирование двумерного массива из хронологических данных в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, codeigniter

Добрый день!
Моя задача казалось бы простая, но у меня никак не выходит оформить в виде кода. 
Есть таблица mysql:

```
category   date
name1     2014-08-28  
name2     2014-08-28
name3     2014-08-27
name3     2014-08-26
name1     2014-08-26
```

На выходе нужно получить массив:

```
array( 2014-08-28 => array(name1,name2),
       2014-08-27 => array(name3),
       2014-08-26 => array(name3,name1)
);
```

Работаю в фреймворке codeigniter, может, в нем есть инструмент, чтоб эту задачу решить более проще?
Потому мне приходилось делать два вызова из бд, кучу циклов и выгладит это как китайский код, очень некрасиво и неграмотно, аж стыдно показывать.

Comment: Прямо в бд вы все равно это толково не сделаете. У вас либо будет приходить дополнительное поле-строка, разделенное запятыми, либо много строк с повторяющимися значениями даты (по факту - прямой селект). Проще всего выдернуть всё и просто прогнать циклом полученное уже в PHP.

Comment: ну так мне и не нужно это делаьт прямо в бд. просто выдернуть например функцией group by два столбца и уже работать с этими данными в пхп. но вот именно это у меня и не получается

Comment: @zinteco, для компоновки результатов по дате в одну строку потребуется функция `GROUP_CONCAT()`, подробнее не скажу, потому что никогда ей не пользовался.

> функцией group by

это не совсем функция

> уже работать с этими данными в пхп. но вот именно это у меня и не получается

    $data = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if (!isset($data[$result['date'])) {
            $data[$result['date']] = array();
        }
        $data[$result['date']][] = $category;
    }

вуаля, в $data все отсортировано.

Comment: Тут не хватает скобочки if (!isset($data[$result['date']])) {

А где вы взяли $category?

Comment: @zinteco, $result['category'], конечно.

Comment: Ну тогда получиться не совсем тот результат.
Получиться, что в одной ячейке массива будут записаны все категории, а мне нужно чтобы каждая категория была в отдельной ячейке, для дальнейшего перебора. Значит и функция GROUP_CONCAT() не подходит, она склеивает все в одну строку(

Comment: > получиться что в одной ячейке массива будут записаны все категории.

никак нет.

> функция GROUP_CONCAT() не подходит, она склеивает все в одну строку(

А я о чем говорил?

У меня осталось 355 символов комментария, и вот на что я их потрачу:

http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru http://tsya.ru

Comment: Получилось, и даже без функции 
    
    SELECT suppliers,date FROM `history` group by suppliers,date

    foreach ($results as $item) {
        
        $data1[$item['date']][] = $item['suppliers'];
    }
Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Можно сгруппировать значения по полям `suppliers` и `date`, а затем в цикле по результирующей таблице сформировать двумерный массив.

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);


    $query = "SELECT
                *
              FROM
                history
              GROUP BY
                suppliers,
                `date`";
    $hst = $pdo->query($query);

    $result = [];
    while($history = $hst->fetch()) {
      $result[$history['date']][] = $history['suppliers'];
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```